# DataTrigger and Storyboard only getting executed once, related to order of declaration?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Here is a minimum toy example that shows the problem I'm having.

I'm creating a WPF app using MVVM. The main ViewModel contains a collection of `ItemViewModel`s. Each item has an enum `Position` property which can be the value `Left`, `Center`, or `Right`.

I want to position each item in the collection according to it's `Position` property. When this value changes it needs to animate to the new position.

Here are the VMs:

**ItemViewModel.cs**

```
public enum Position
{
   Left, Center, Right
}

public class ItemViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _myData;
    private Position _position;

    public string MyData
    {
        get { return _myData; } set { SetProperty(ref _myData, value); }
    }
    public Position Position
    {
        get { return _position; } set { SetProperty(ref _position, value); }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand Switch { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Switch = new DelegateCommand(DoSwitch);

        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { MyData = "I1", Position = Position.Left });
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { MyData = "I2", Position = Position.Right });
    }

    private void DoSwitch()
    {
        var p = Items[0].Position;
        Items[0].Position = Items[1].Position;
        Items[1].Position = p;
    }
}
```

I'm binding `ViewModel.Items` to an `ItemsControl` and then using `DataTrigger`s to start `Storyboard`s which are animating the margin based on the `Position` property.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>

    <Button Content="Switch" Command="{Binding Switch}"/>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding MyData}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,0,0,0"/>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Position}" Value="{x:Static local:Position.Left}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                     Duration="0:0:1"
                                                     To="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Position}" Value="{x:Static local:Position.Center}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                     Duration="0:0:1"
                                                     To="100,0,0,0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Position}" Value="{x:Static local:Position.Right}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                     Duration="0:0:1"
                                                     To="200,0,0,0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

**The Issue**

Clicking the "Switch" button should animate the item on the left to the right, and vise versa. However, it only animates to the right (from `Left` to `Center` or `Right`, or from `Center` to `Right`). It does not animate to the left (`Right` to `Center` or `Left`, or `Center` to `Left`).

Whats even stranger, is that if I reverse the order of the `DataTrigger` declaration in the XAML then it will only animate in the other direction (right to left).

If I remove the animation and just set the margin as a `Setter` in the trigger then it works as expected. Also, if I set `FillBehavior` to `Stop` then it will animate each time, left or right, but then "snaps" back to the default value.

It looks as if the system is only executing a `Storyboard` that is later in XAML declaration than the current "active" `DataTrigger`.

Why is this occurring? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(VS.95).aspx

The filling behavior can create the illusion that a property is unsettable at runtime if you are not careful about stopping unintended animations. Attempting to change the animated value coming from a filling animation in code will appear to have no effect until the filling animation is stopped.

Example: change your animations (warning: all of them) to

```
<ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:1" To="0" 
                    FillBehavior="Stop" />
```

And everything will work. But it will reset value between animations.

Comment: Thanks code monkey. As noted in the question, we noticed that setting the fill behavior to `Stop` would "fix" the issue, but it's not really a fix since the whole point of the animations are for the app to look nice and jumping from one position to another (i.e. `FillBehavior="Stop"`) isn't a workable solution. =( Additionally, the existing storyboards shouldn't need to be stopped since the default handoff behavior is to `SnapshotAndReplace`, so there should only ever be one animation running on an item at a time.