# Is there a workaround for throttled WPF DataTrigger events?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding

Coming from [Why is this WPF animation only triggered once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67696320/why-is-this-wpf-animation-only-triggered-once), I eventually found out that WPF does indeed throttle its' binding events.

The code below demonstrates the behavior: clicking a button starts a task with a loop of 100 iterations that updates a property every 2ms. A control bound to this property counts how many times `DataContextChanged` was fired.

On my machine, if I click the button 5 times, the output is something like this:

```
Iterations: 100, Count: 86
Iterations: 100, Count: 87
Iterations: 100, Count: 85
Iterations: 100, Count: 89
Iterations: 100, Count: 90
```

My original problem (I thought, see link above) was that an animation was only triggered once. I then found out, that it wasn't the animation, it was the `DataTrigger` that wasn't responding. Then I studied the behavior of `DataContextChanged` (see code) and now assume that basically WPF throttles all events.

I wanted to define the animation in XAML only, which means I have to depend on `DataTrigger` firing "correctly" as in "always". It apparently doesn't. Must I - in order to achieve the animation I originally intended - implement my own event (that will not get throttled) and trigger the animation from code?

**EDIT:**

- To clarify: I do not want to trigger an animation every 2ms! The animation should only be triggered when a specific value is set - and that will only happen on user interaction, typically once every few seconds at most in my current setting.
- But: The observed property will only have that specific value for a very short time, e.g. 2ms. And, apparently, just this property change can go lost due to WPF's throttling (as pointed out in an answer below).
- So, the question remains: *Must I ... implement my own event ... and trigger the animation from code?*

**AnimationTestControl.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="AnimationTests.AnimationTestControl"
             x:Name="self"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimationTests"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=self}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Toggle Border" Click="ButtonToggle_Click" />

            <Border x:Name="TestBorder" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=TestBorderItem.MyState}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**AnimationTestControl.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace AnimationTests
{

    public class TestItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _myState;
        public int MyState
        {
            get => _myState;
            set { _myState = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public partial class AnimationTestControl : UserControl
    {
        public AnimationTestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public TestItem TestBorderItem { get; } = new TestItem();

        private void ButtonToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var cnt = 0;
                var max = 100;
                void handler(object s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) => cnt++;
                
                TestBorder.DataContextChanged += handler;

                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                {
                    TestBorderItem.MyState = i + 1;
                    Thread.Sleep(2);
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"{max}: {cnt}");

                TestBorder.DataContextChanged -= handler;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With regards to your question in the topic.
I do not understand what your research has to do with finding out the reason.
You don't need to run your animation at 2ms, do you?

Comment: How many times are you going to ssk what is effectively the same question?

Comment: @Andy: ...because in the beginning i thought it was an Animation/Storyboard issue - but it turned out to be something more underlying, and details of the original question were irrelevant, which is why i asked a fresh question.

Answer (score -1):

All actions with user interface elements occur through the Dispatcher queue of the main application thread.
Below I am writing not an exact, but an approximate scenario of work.

When you change any property in the ViewModel, a task is created to change the property of the UI element (via binding), and this task is pushed to the Dispatcher queue.
The next time you change the ViewModel property, the next task will be queued.
If you change the value of the ViewModel property very quickly, chances are that the next task will be queued before the previous one.
When the first task starts, it reads the current value of the ViewModel property, and this will no longer be the first property value, but the second.
The binding will change the property value of the UI element, and this change will trigger the corresponding event, which will also be executed in the same task.
After processing the event, the first task will be completed.
After a while, the turn of the second task will begin.
The binding will re-assign the current value of the ViewModel property.
But the element's UI property already contains this value.
And since the value of the property of the UI element has not changed, then, accordingly, an event about its change will not be generated.

**Added in response to request:**

> if you could provide a XAML only solution (that would help keeping logic and design separated) that would be great!

**IMPLEMENTATION.**

For use in XAML, you need to modify the DataTrigger to check for a value on the PropertyChanged event stream.
But changing the DataTrigger is tricky.
Many of its members are declared `internal`.

Therefore, will have to create your own intermediate trigger (CockedTrigger) that will be cocked according to a given condition.
The DataTrigger will be bound to the CockedTrigger property.
After completing the actions, you must discharge the trigger.
To do this, have to create an Attached Property used in the Animation.

The CockedTrigger will be created in Resources and needs bindings, so it must be derived from Freezable.
Also, it will partially work not in the Dispatcher thread, therefore, an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` is needed and all the necessary DependecyProperties values ​​are additionally stored in private fields.

There was a lot of code.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace Proxy
{
    public class CockedTrigger : Freezable, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
               => new CockedTrigger();

        /// <summary>The binding source.</summary>
        public object Source
        {
            get => GetValue(SourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Source"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Source), typeof(object), typeof(CockedTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(null, SourceChanged));

        private static void SourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CockedTrigger trigget = (CockedTrigger)d;
            if (e.OldValue is INotifyPropertyChanged oldTarget)
            {
                oldTarget.PropertyChanged -= trigget.OnObservablePropertyChanged;
            }

            if (e.NewValue is INotifyPropertyChanged newTarget)
            {
                trigget.SetPropertyFunc();
                newTarget.PropertyChanged += trigget.OnObservablePropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        public Func<object> PropertyFunc
        {
            get => _propertyFunc; private set
            {
                if (!Equals(_propertyFunc, value))
                {
                    _propertyFunc = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, PropertyFuncPropertyChangedEventArgs);
                }
            }
        }
        private Func<object> _propertyFunc;
        private static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs PropertyFuncPropertyChangedEventArgs
            = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(PropertyFunc));

        private object fieldSource;
        private string fieldProperty;
        private void SetPropertyFunc()
        {
            fieldSource = Source;
            fieldProperty = Property;
            PropertyFunc = GetValuePropertyFunc(Source, Property);
        }

        public static Func<object> GetValuePropertyFunc(object source, string propertyName)
        {
            if (source == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            {
                return null;
            }

            Type type = source.GetType();
            PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

            if (property == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (property.PropertyType.IsClass ||
                property.PropertyType.IsInterface ||
                property.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                return (Func<object>)property?.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>), source);
            }

            if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType ||
                property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                Type funcType = typeof(Func<>);
                Type funcTypeGeneric = funcType.MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType);
                Delegate funcDelegate = property.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(funcTypeGeneric, source);
                return () => funcDelegate.DynamicInvoke();
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException($"Not implemented for property type {property.PropertyType.FullName}.");
        }

        private void OnObservablePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldProperty) &&
                e.PropertyName == fieldProperty &&
                PropertyFunc != null &&
                Equals(PropertyFunc(), fieldValue))
            {
                IsTriggerCocked = true;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>Name observable Property.</summary>
        public string Property
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(PropertyProperty);
            set => SetValue(PropertyProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Property"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Property), typeof(string), typeof(CockedTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(null,
                (d, e) => ((CockedTrigger)d).SetPropertyFunc()));


        /// <summary>Comparison value.</summary>
        public object Value
        {
            get => GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Value"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(object), typeof(CockedTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(null,
                (d, e) => ((CockedTrigger)d).fieldValue = e.NewValue));
        private object fieldValue;


        /// <summary>
        /// Read-only property.
        /// Returns true if, after changing the observed property, its value is equal to the expected value.
        /// Can return to false only with the UnloadTrigger method.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsTriggerCocked
        {
            get => _isTriggerCocked; private set
            {
                if (!Equals(_isTriggerCocked, value))
                {

                    _isTriggerCocked = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, IsTriggerCockedPropertyChangedEventArgs);
                }
            }
        }
        private bool _isTriggerCocked;
        private static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs IsTriggerCockedPropertyChangedEventArgs
            = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsTriggerCocked));

        public void UnloadTrigger() => IsTriggerCocked = false;

        public static CockedTrigger GetResetWhenCompleted(Timeline animation)
        {
            return (CockedTrigger)animation.GetValue(ResetWhenCompletedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetResetWhenCompleted(Timeline animation, CockedTrigger value)
        {
            animation.SetValue(ResetWhenCompletedProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ResetWhenCompleted.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ResetWhenCompletedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ResetWhenCompleted", typeof(CockedTrigger), typeof(CockedTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(null, ResetWhenCompletedChanged));

        private static void ResetWhenCompletedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(d is Timeline animation))
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException($"Implemented only for classes derived from {nameof(Timeline)}.");
            }

            if (e.OldValue is CockedTrigger oldTrigger)
            {
                animation.Completed -= oldTrigger.UnloadTrigger;
            }
            if (e.NewValue is CockedTrigger newTrigger)
            {
                animation.Completed += newTrigger.UnloadTrigger;
            }
        }

        private void UnloadTrigger(object sender, EventArgs e)
            => UnloadTrigger();

        protected override bool FreezeCore(bool isChecking)
        {
            if (isChecking)
                return true;

            object source = fieldSource;
            object value = fieldValue;
            string property = fieldProperty;

            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this, SourceProperty);
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this, ValueProperty);
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this, PropertyProperty);

            Source = source;
            Value = value;
            Property = property;

            return base.FreezeCore(isChecking);
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE EXAMPLE.**

A simple ViewModel, in which, at a given interval, the `AnyProperty` property for the minimum possible instant is set to true and immediately reset back to false.
For the convenience of testing, the remaining interval until the next jump in the value is also displayed.

```
using Simplified;
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace CheckingProxyTrigger
{
    public class CptViewModel : BaseInpc
    {
        private bool _anyProperty;
        private double _tickInterval = 10; // 10 s
        private double _intervalToNextTick;

        public bool AnyProperty { get => _anyProperty; set => Set(ref _anyProperty, value); }
        public double TickInterval { get => _tickInterval; set => Set(ref _tickInterval, value); }

        public double IntervalToNextTick { get => _intervalToNextTick; private set => Set(ref _intervalToNextTick, value); }

        private DateTime nextTime;

        private readonly Timer timer = new Timer()
        {
            Interval = 10 // 10 ms
        };

        public CptViewModel()
        {
            nextTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(TickInterval);
            timer.Elapsed += OnTick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void OnTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            IntervalToNextTick = (nextTime - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds;

            if (IntervalToNextTick <= 0)
            {
                timer.Stop();

                AnyProperty = true;
                AnyProperty = false;

                nextTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(TickInterval);
                timer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The window consists of several `TextBlock` that track various states.

One of them uses the binding of the Data Context to `AnyProperty` and handling the event of its change to count the value jumps.
On each jump, the event (according to logic) should be called twice.
Once when going to True, the second time when returning to False.
But because of the queue, only one event is processed.

Below there are two `Border`.
One is set to inimation from the jumping property.
It works only on the first jump.

The second is from the CockedTrigger in resources.
It works for every jump.

```
<Window x:Class="CheckingProxyTrigger.CptWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckingProxyTrigger" xmlns:proxy="clr-namespace:Proxy;assembly=Common"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CptWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <local:CptViewModel/>
    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <proxy:CockedTrigger x:Key="trigger"
                             Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
                             Property="AnyProperty">
            <proxy:CockedTrigger.Value>
                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
            </proxy:CockedTrigger.Value>
        </proxy:CockedTrigger>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Interval until next tick:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding IntervalToNextTick, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:F1\}}"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding AnyProperty}" DataContextChanged="TextBlock_DataContextChanged">
            <Run Text="Count of property value changes:"/>
            <Run x:Name="countChanges" Text="0"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Trigger cocked:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding IsTriggerCocked, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource trigger}}"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <Border Height="50" Width="50">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ActualWidth" Value="50">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnyProperty}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                         From="400"
                                                         To="50"
                                                         Duration="0:0:2"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
        <Border Height="50" Width="50" Margin="10">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ActualWidth" Value="50">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTriggerCocked, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource trigger}}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                         From="400"
                                                         To="50"
                                                         Duration="0:0:2"
                                                         proxy:CockedTrigger.ResetWhenCompleted="{StaticResource trigger}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CheckingProxyTrigger
{
    public partial class CptWindow : Window
    {
        public CptWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int count;
        private void TextBlock_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (countChanges != null)
            {
                count++;
                countChanges.Text = count.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's pretty much what i assumed (which, technically, isn't throttling, i guess), but does not answer the question: Must I ... implement my own event ... and trigger the animation from code?

Comment: For a more accurate answer, I need to know the details of the task you are implementing.
I already wrote about this in the comments to your question.
It is not clear what kind of animation is it that should be triggered 500 times per second?
It makes no sense to do such an animation anyway.
Even if you create an event and call the animation on Sharpe, the animation itself must still be executed in the Dispatcher queue.
Thus, you will return in a different way, but to the same problem.

Comment: please read my edits: I do not want to trigger an animation every 2ms!

Comment: Now I read it and understood what the problem is.
I need to think about the optimal solution.
I will answer later.

Comment: If you need this for a one-time use, then the easiest way is to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event and check the property value in its handler.
If this is the expected value, then start the animation.

Comment: It is possible to make a solution for use only in XAML, but it will be much more difficult to implement.
Although easier to apply.
This requires creating an additional class and/or Attached Property.
If this makes sense to you, then I can try to implement something like this.

Comment: i went with subscribing to the event and triggering the animation from code, but, if you could provide a XAML only solution (that would help keeping logic and design separated) that would be great! also, i would find it very interesting to see how you'd do it, since i'm assuming the Dispatcher invocation (that leads to the "throttle effect" as you nicely laid out above) happens pretty far up-stream - wouldn't any XAML implementation have the same issues?

Comment: I supplement my answer.
I don’t know how useful it will be to you.